# Variable index/vlookup

Tags: variables, indexing, lookup

I have found a much neater way of achieving what I want using the formula below as it allows users to add additional customers to search for without the need to edit the formula! also the formula would be a mile shorter!

The formula below works nicely but Ideally I want the formula to check additional worksheets for a match if the result is not found on the first attempt and lookup a different workbook depending on the worksheet the match is found in.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Estimate!C4,'204 Customers'!A:A,0)),"No Match",INDEX('K:\204 Central Accounts\Bib\[Bib Ops Center.xlsm]FPS_Parts'!$D$3:$D$90000,MATCH(Estimate!B50,'K:\204 Central Accounts\Bib\[Bib Ops Center.xlsm]FPS_Parts'!$B$3:$B$90000,0)))
```

Example below of what am trying to achieve whilst it does not work I think it explains what I want to do! excel accepts the formula but I get "#VALUE!" as a result not sure where am going wrong but sure its something simple!!

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Estimate!C4,'204 Customers'!A:A,0)),"No Match",INDEX('K:\204 Central Accounts\Bib\[Bib Ops Center.xlsm]FPS_Parts'!$D$3:$D$90000,MATCH(Estimate!B50,'K:\204 Central Accounts\Bib\[Bib Ops Center.xlsm]FPS_Parts'!$B$3:$B$90000,0))),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Estimate!C4,'772 Customers'!A:A,0)),INDEX('K:\ESL 772\Info Centre\[772 Ops Center.xlsm]Parts'!$F$5:$F$90000,MATCH(Estimate!B51,'K:\ESL 772\Info Centre\[772 Ops Center.xlsm]Parts'!$B$5:$B$90000,0),"No Match"))
```

Hope someone can help me close this one down.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide error messages as text, not as screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: The error message just says "The formula you typed contains error" standard message.